# Trying to load an image to magnific gallery results in CORB problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup, cross-origin-read-blocking, instafeedjs

I am trying to load an image to a magnific gallery pop-up, however whenever I click on the image I get an error on the webpage: "The image could not be loaded", while "The image" in this error message is a link to an Instagram account, which I am dragging the images from. In the console I get a CORB error.

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https:{link to a file that is displayed on my webpage dragged from Instagram with instafeed.js} with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

```
Image (async)
getImage @ magnific.min.js:4
updateItemHTML @ magnific.min.js:4
next @ magnific.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ magnific.min.js:4
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.js:5183
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4991
```

Is there a way to avoid this CORB issue? Alternatively, how can I display those images from Instagram (which I am getting using instafeed.js) in a modal pop-up?